# Switch PCI device to D3 cold (D3cold) state

Tags: c, unix, linux-kernel, power-management, pci

I need to phisically power off my PCI device in linux. I have find the functions I need, but it seems to write a kernel mode application to use that library, because I have find it in kernel headers.

I have found this function `int pci_set_power_state(struct pci_dev *dev, pci_power_t state)` in drivers/pci/pci.c and I don't know how to use it.

Also, I've read in documentation, that device driver in general is not used to switch device to d3cold, because the device simply switches off and don't work at all (yes, there are some devices, that can be switched off not completely, and are able to send a wake up call, but this is another story...) and I think, that I need to communicate with PCI bus.

I don't know where to look for an answer, please guide my quest.

Comment: I hardly understand the context. Are you having some issue with some device? Do you want to manage the device via userspace? Does the device have a driver in kernel? Be more elaborative.

Comment: I want to switch off any power of any PCI-device. In my situation it has driver, but i don't know either it compiled in kernel or not. Kernel or userspace is not important, but userspace application is more comfortable to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potential Method #1
I think you can do it with these commands:

disable

> echo 0 > /sys/bus/pci/slots/$NUMBER/power

enable

> echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/slots/$NUMBER/power

Where $NUMBER is the number of the PCI slot.

lspci -vv may help to identify the device. This is not very well documented...

Comment: Thank you.

I already found this but forgot to post answer. I finally used this command to switch device off: `echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:03\:00.0/remove`
and this command to switch it on: `echo 1 blur > /sys/bus/pci/rescan`.
I really don't sure that it switches device to D3cold state, but it did the trick for me. To see if d3cold allowed read `/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:03\:00.0/d3cold_allowed`.

Comment: What distro do you use? I have `power` only as a directory in my sysfs (`4.15.0-55-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 2 18:22:20 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`).

Comment: @RomanKovtuh Writing to "remove" does not put it into D3cold. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/PCI/sysfs-pci.html

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to send shutdown notification to pci device. I take nvm device for example

1. read bar0 value by lspci, offset is 10h.

   lspci -s 01:00.0 -xxxx. For example you got value: 0xfc1f4004
2. read memory whose addr is 0xfc1f4000
3. write 1 in bit 14 of 0xfc1f4014

Offset 14h: CC – Controller Configuration.  Bit 15:14 = 01b  Normal shutdown notification